# 5 identical questions: coding competition or just classmates/colleagues?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

In the past few days I've seen 5 identical questions posted with the algorithm tag (one seems to have been deleted):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877125/dont-understand-how-to-solve
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930872/how-to-find-the-minimum-number-of-bits-to-uniquely-identify-k-2d-binary-matrices
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932823/minimum-number-of-comparisons-to-check-if-n-matrices-are-distinct
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935241/differentiate-k-number-of-arrays

They are all about how many bits you need to check to differentiate between six letter stored as 3×3 bitmaps, something like:

```
100    111    101    111    111    111
100    010    111    010    100    101
111    010    101    111    111    111    = L T H I C O
```

Does anyone recognise this as a question from an ongoing competition?

Or could the claim made by one of the askers, that he was asked this at a job interview, be true, and did these 5 people all just happen to apply for the same job?

*(It's also interesting to see how one of these was closed, one was upvoted, two were downvoted, and all were answered, which is typical of the unpredictable reaction to questions with the algorithm tag.)*

Comment: Now they have all been downvoted, which is typical of questions mentioned on Meta. :-)

Comment: And here is one more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943868/find-a-generalised-code

Comment: @CodyGray Roomba targeting system primed... duplicate flags dropped... targeting system engaged... oblivion-level downvote process primed... fire for EFFECT!!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think Google has the answers. I searched for the exact text of the first question and I found [this website](http://blog.csdn.net/woainiwss/article/details/51559804).

It says it's for "Exam 1 Character Recognition - Works Application 16". The assignment is in English, but the rest of the site is Chinese (including the comments in the code).

I'm not sure if it's actually for a job interview. It seems like a really weird format for a job interview.

I doubt that it's a school assignment, since school shouldn't have started yet.

Note that I also got a bunch of other results for other Q&A programming sites. Clearly, the duplication is not isolated to this network.

---

Update:

I think I figured it out... "Works Application[s]" isn't some type of broken English, it's a company!

The connection with the company is also supported by the answer on one of the [sites](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/7805/character-recognition):

> worksapplication垃圾公司别去

The Chinese appears to be saying "Do not go to the garbage company".

The page [here](http://www.kanzhun.com/gsm602242.html) is essentially the Chinese version of [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Works-Applications-Interview-Questions-E255230.htm).

After looking into the company, they are Japanese, but have offices in a number of other countries, including China and the US. It appears that they are outsourcing some work to China (where the salary may be considered a lot of money). The interview question is likely the first test, which is given to a lot of applicants as part of the screening process.

It now makes a bit more sense (rough translations):

> Two written programming topics, three days to complete. Because it is not on-site, you can find the information to solve it.

....

> Two questions, one was a trie, [the other was about] character recognition.

Comment: School starts differently on asian countries (ie. we are in the times of midterms for japaneses)

Comment: @Braiam :P I don't want to hear it. (Context: I'm currently in college and not ready to go back for the year.)

Comment: Running the Chinese page through Google Translate shows a mention of this being a job interview question. Maybe the page just lists questions found on the net, and it's not the primary source?

Comment: If it was the primary source, it wouldn't have listed the answer on the same page in plain view.

Comment: @MrLister You're right; I dug further and I think I found the original source. (See edits.)

Comment: It is worth noting that this **WORKS APPLICATIONS** is a **Japanese** company. source: http://www.kanzhun.com/gsm602242.html (in Chinese)

Comment: @paradite That explains some of the comments I saw on that page (I already linked there). But it's not unusual for companies to be globalized, especially IT companies.

Comment: @Laurel Great investigative work!

Comment: @Laurel to depress you some more, in Sri Lanka the school graduation exams (we call this the Advanced Levels similar to Britain) are in progress. But for other grades this is merely a mid year break. In september they will resume the final term of the year.

Comment: I'd love to see the stats for that page before and after that link was featured on a Meta answer. "OMG!  DDOS! ... Oh, wait, it's the Meta effect."  :-p

Comment: 3 of 4 of the users asking these are students of computer science at indian universities.

Comment: @m69 The company is definitely doing job interviews. It is pretty clear if you [translate the second page into English](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kanzhun.com%2Fgsm602242.html&edit-text=) with things like _"Interview difficulty: 3.1,"_ etc.  I also find this interesting: _"Get an interview sources
 Online recruitment 5% |
 Campus Recruiting 90%."_  I suppose these people might be part of the 5% doing the online recruitment? Look at the rating reviewer locations: Shanghai (4 people), Tokyo (4 people), Beijing, and Wuhan.

Comment: @Laurel I work at a college, and we're never actually "closed". Yay, summer semesters...